# Unique combinations

Tags: sas

I'm looking to examine unique combinations of 7 binary variables (cannabis modes of delivery [yes/no]) and was under the impression this should be a fairly simple task in SAS. However, all of the coding examples I've come across online seem a bit overcomplicated for such a basic process. If anyone has insight regarding this concept I would appreciate it!

Comment: Show an example input and required output.  You can limit to 2 or 3 variables to make it easier as most solutions should be easy to expand the number of variables.

Comment: I have Var1, Var2, and Var3. 
My aim is to find the proportion of my sample who fall into each unique category of these variables (i.e. those who are Var1=1, Var2=1, & Var3=1, vs. Var1=1, Var2=1, & Var3=0, etc.)
My code thus far was this simple proc freq syntax:
proc freq data=temp; 
table Var1*Var2*Var3;
run;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
proc sort data=yourdataset(Keep=Variables to examine seperated by blanks) out=choose_a_name noduprec;
  by Variables to examine seperated by blanks;
run;
```

Resulting dataset choose_a_name will contain all unique combinations of examined variables.

Answer (score 1):

So if you want the counts probably it easiest to use PROC SUMMARY.

```
proc summary data=have nway missing ;
  class var1-var7 ;
  output out=want(rename=(_freq_=count));
run;
```

Comment: As there is no analysis variable the N statistic is invalid.  The automatic variable \_FREQ\_ will be count.